# CSS translate3d is scaling chaotically when hover (Chrome)

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Basically CSS 3d transform is jumping (or scaling chaotically)  on hover event.
To see this glitch you need to hover in and out quickly several times (only Chrome). 
[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/alexlime/gmCU6/)
[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/K3yRH/)

Code is as simple as possible:

```
<div></div>

div {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out,
                        background 0.3s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) translate3d(10px, 10px, 20px);
}
```

I have tried to attach the -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; as I found this solution in  related jumping/flashing issue in Chrome, but in my case it did nothing at all.

Does anyone know this issue? Or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're not providing any default translate values on your elements prior to their `:hover` states. Simply add in default values for these and the problem goes away:

#### Example 1

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out,
                        background 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmCU6/1/).

#### Example 2

```css
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3yRH/344/).

Comment: I have the same glitch in your code. Can you check first example it is much more simple

Comment: @Alex which example are you looking at and which browser are you using? Both examples in my answer seem to be working correctly in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex Please see Example 1 in my answer. This uses `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Ok, yes, now I see. I got confused too many tabs with jsFiddles was open :) Thank you!